# キャッシュの書き込みは、キャッシュ内の全てのデータが同時に上書きされるのでしょうか。キャッシュの中の1行ずつ上書きすることは可能でしょうか。

Tags: ハードウェア, cpu

以下の記事について、疑問点があります。

[コンピュータアーキテクチャの話(139) ダイレクトマップキャッシュとその注意点 | TECH+（テックプラス）](https://news.mynavi.jp/techplus/article/architecture-139/)

キャッシュのデータを書き換えるときは、そのキャッシュラインに入っているすべてのデータを同時に書き換えるのでしょうか？上記のサイトでは、`a[0] ~ a[7]` を読み込んだ後、キャッシュミスが発生するため、`b[0] ~ b[7]` をすべて読み込んで、書き込む形をとっていますが、単に `b[0]` 1個だけ読み込んで（これと同時に、キャッシュラインにすでにある `a[0] ~ a[7]` のいずれか1つが上書きされて、データがキャッシュから消える）書き込み、次に、`b[1]` を読み込んで…というふうに、1つずつ読み込むことはできないのでしょうか。
この理由が分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 念のため、[ハッシュ（`hash`）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5)と[キャッシュ（`cache`）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5_(%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0))は別の用語です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> キャッシュのデータを書き換えるときは、そのキャッシュラインに入っているすべてのデータを同時に書き換えるのでしょうか？

そうです

> 1つずつ読み込むことはできないのでしょうか。
> この理由

理由というか「データを同時に書き換える」単位をキャッシュラインと定義しています

> データとペアで格納するアドレスデータをタグ(Tag:海外旅行のスーツケースに付けるような荷札という意味))という。そして、データとタグのペアをキャッシュラインと呼ぶ。

とそのサイトに有るようにキャッシュラインは上位アドレスが共通で
下位アドレスだけでアクセスできる連続領域である必要があります

> 単に b[0] 1個だけ読み込んで（これと同時に、キャッシュラインにすでにある a[0] ~ a[7] のいずれか1つが上書き

これをやろうとすると 0 番が &a のアドレスで 1-7 が &b と混ざった状態とするにはキャッシュタグが a b どっちをもてばいいかわからないですよね

---

じゃあキャッシュラインサイズ１にして全部のキャッシュに別々のアドレスもてばいいじゃん
って考えるんですがハードウェアの世界でそんな柔軟なことをすると回路効率が著しく悪くなります

たとえばキャッシュラインサイズは１６～２５６が多いですが
１６の場合に比べてキャッシュラインを１にすると
アドレスマッチング回路も１６倍必要になるし
データ１６個に対して上位アドレス１つもてばいいのが
データ１つに上位アドレス１つ保つ必要があり、
データに使える記憶領域が半分になってしまいます

---

おそらくこの先の説明に出てくるんだと思うんですが
インテルの i7 なんかは 4way セットアソシアティブっていって
下位アドレスが共通なキャッシュラインを４つまでもつことができます

さらにAMDの場合はビクティムキャッシュって言って
キャッシュミスしたキャッシュラインを
全下位アドレス共通で使える少量のフルアソシアティブ領域でもっておくっていう方法でキャッシュミスを緩和してます

Comment: 詳細な回答をしていただき、ありがとうございます。アドレスマッチング回路についてですが、いただいた回答では、キャッシュライン一つにつき、アドレスマッチング回路は1つと想定していらっしゃると思います。一方で、キャッシュラインサイズ16の場合は、最終的にキャッシュラインのデータをすべて取ってきた後に、下位アドレスが一致するものを探すため、もう一度アドレスマッチング回路が必要になると思うのですが、実際にはハードウェアとして、どのような仕組みで、下位アドレスの一致するデータを取り出しているのか、教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: > どのような仕組み　ミクロな視点でみるとただのマルチプレクサの集合です。そのマルチプレクサが何個いるかってはなしになります。https://www.am.ics.keio.ac.jp/parthenon/cache.pdf　これとかがわかりやすいかも。２５Pと２７Pにダイレクトマップと 2way セットアソシアティブの例がのってますが、キャッシュサイズを１にするということはフルアソシアティブ=16way セットアソシアティブで組むということなので、左のアドレスブロックとピンクの「＝」回路が１６倍必要になるってことです

Comment: お忙しい中、いつも詳細な回答ありがとうございます。また、Cacheについて詳細な解説が載っているリンクを共有していただき、Cacheについて、さらに理解を深めることができました。リンクのp24について、質問がさらにあるのですが、インデックスを用いて、キャッシュディレクトリとキャッシュにアクセスしたうえで、タグが一致した場合には、そのアドレスに相当するブロック（リンクの例では、8byte）ごとCPUに渡すのでしょうか。つまり、この場合でも、最終的にCPUが欲しいデータはそのブロックの中の全8個のデータのうち、一つだけだと思うのですが、この比較判定→一つだけを選び出すという処理は、どこで行われるのでしょうか。CPUのほうでしょうか。それとも、Cacheのほうでしょうか。

Comment: キャッシュはCPUの一部なのでCPUの中のキャッシュの中で行われます。ダイのうちその選択回路がどこにレイアウトされるかはインテルの人にきかないとわからないですが、配線コストを考えるとキャッシュのストレージ領域のかなり近くにレイアウトされていると思います